# Encrypt USB Stick with AES 128/256

Tags: encryption

I am trying to encrypt my USB stick with AES 128/256 encryption. I am new to the game and need some advice, google has not been my friend so far.

All i would like to do is encrypt the whole USB stick so that i end up with one like this [AES USB.](https://www.officemonster.co.uk/StoreFront/evolution_product.html?Product=Integral-Crypto-Encrypted-USB-4Gb-Flash-Drive-Grey-INFD4GCRYPTO197&IdProduct=1083270&fo_c=734&fo_k=ad984d2ab3cafd1ef1cada21f4130850&fo_s=gplauk&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3YOzp5ft1AIVhQrTCh3KfwH9EAYYBCABEgLYIfD_BwE#.WVpBvIjyuUk)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it does not support integrated encryption creating a veracrypt volume on it is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your choices for encryption:

1. Hardware encryption - get an USB flash drive that has the encryption logic programmed into its firmware (like the one you linked to).

   - **Pros:** Works in any operating system, no software installation necessary.
   - **Cons:** This is a more expensive option.
2. Software encryption - either get a flash drive that comes with a software, or download and install software that will encrypt your drive.

   - **Pros:** Less expensive option, some of good software to do this is either free or low-cost.
   - **Cons:** The software is operating system specific, so if you need a cross-OS approach, then you will have to find a program that has versions for multiple operating systems. Also the software will either need to be installed on any computer you will stick the flash drive into (most probably requiring you to be an administrator on that computer), or hopefully it can have a portable version that can be run directly from the USB drive.

Most  USB flash sticks manufacturers have hardware-encrypted sticks in their assortment - you can ask around and read some reviews and choose one to your liking.

For software programs - the easiest option for Windows is its built-in BitLocker program, it is available on most recent Windows versions.

For cross-platform - look at tools like VeraCrypt, GNU Privacy Guard and others (again do your research and pick the one you like).

Another viable option is just to put the files you want to restrict access to in a password-protected ZIP archive.

Hope this helps.